# Determine whether a point lies on a vector line

Tags: vectors

> Determine whether the given point $P(5,1,4)$ lies on the line $\vec r = (1 , 3, 4) + \lambda (2, -1, 0)$.

I don't where to start, or how to do this question.

Answer (score 4):

your point is situated on the line since
$$5=1+2\lambda$$
$$1=3-\lambda$$
$$4=4+0\lambda$$
solving this system we get $$\lambda=2$$

Comment: Your last equation is wrong....and the point is on the line, in fact.

Comment: There is a typo. Last equation should be $4=4+0\lambda$, thus this system of equations admits a unique solution as $\lambda=2$

Comment: yes it was still a little typo

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Substitute the point $P$ in the equation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\1\\4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\3\\4
\end{pmatrix}
+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
2\\-1\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you can say that it has the solution $\lambda=2$.